# How to scrape images from shopify sites

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to export images from HTML on an TXT file, mostly from Shopify sites. Most of the img's from Shopify sites structures are the same. For some reason, I can't scrape the image links. I just need the first link.

Here is an example of one HTML tag.

```
<div class="grid-product__content"><a class="grid-product__link" href="/products/ayla-ring-gold">
<div class="grid-product__image-mask"><div class="grid__image-ratio grid__image-ratio--square">
<img alt="Ayla Ring | Gold - Alexa Kelley" class="lazyload grid__image-contain" data-aspectratio="1.0" data-sizes="auto" data-src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Ayla_Ring_Gold_Hero_{width}x.jpg?v=1660506192" data-widths="[360, 540, 720, 900, 1080]"/>
</div><div class="grid-product__secondary-image small--hide"><img alt="Ayla Ring | Gold - Alexa Kelley" class="lazyload" data-aspectratio="1.0" data-sizes="auto" data-src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Ayla_Ring_Gold_2_{width}x.jpg?v=1660506192" data-widths="[360, 540, 720, 1000]"/>
</div></div>
<div class="grid-product__meta">
<div class="grid-product__title grid-product__title--body">Ayla Ring | Gold</div><div class="grid-product__price"><span class="money">$85.00 USD</span>
```

The error that is returned, is " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' ". I know what the error means, I just can't figure how to get the links.

Here is my code...

```
baseurl = ('https://alexakelley.com')
protocol = ('https:')

dataset = []

with open(r'/run/user/759001103/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.0.150,share=indexserver/Country/USA/A/Alexakelley/alexakelley2.txt', "r") as f:

    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), "html.parser")
for e in soup.find('div', class_='grid grid--uniform'):
        dataset.append({
            'Field_01':protocol + e.find('img', class_='grid__image-contain lazyautosizes lazyloaded').get('data-srcset'),
            'Field_02':e.find('div', class_='grid-product__title grid-product__title--body').get_text(strip=True),
            'Field_03':baseurl + e.find('a', class_='grid-product__link').get('href'),
            'Field_04':e.find('span', class_='money').get_text(strip=True)
        })
        df = pd.DataFrame(dataset).to_csv(r'/run/user/759001103/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.0.150,share=indexserver/Country/USA/A/Alexakelley/Alexakelley All.csv', index = False)
        print(dataset)
```

If I omit Field_01, Field02 - Field04 return results, so my code functions. What can I do with the Field_01 line of code?

Comment: But I don't see any `img` tags with *`class='grid__image-contain lazyautosizes lazyloaded'`* or *`data-srcset`* attributes in your HTML snippet? The two `img` tags in the snippet have class `lazyload grid__image-contain` and `lazyload`, and links in the `data-src` atrribute...

Comment: Hi Driftr95, I probably forgot to remove it the class that's there. I tried both attributes you metioned. Got the same error.

Comment: the error is due to nothing matching `.find` parameters; not having the attribute in `.get` will just return `None`, not raise an error. What I meant was that for the `img` tags in your snippet, you should be using `class_="lazyload grid__image-contain"` or `{"class":"lazyload"}` (Btw, you should use something [like this](https://pastebin.com/ff8822tu) if you want to avoid raising ) *` AttributeError: 'NoneType' ....`* from chaining *`.find...`* and *`.get...`*

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the approach by getting all elements that matches with the classes you identified (*those are stored in ResultSets*) - and then loop the items contained in each soup/ResultSet for get the element in the position and build the dataset/list.

> ***NOTE***: in my tests, I found 23 items, but, the last resultset "`spans with money`"has 24 elements, so, consider this inconsistence.

Here is the modified code:

```
# Your list:
dataset = []

# All the resultset (i.e the HTML elements you desired for this task): 
images = soup.find_all("img", class_="grid__image-contain")
divs_field_2 = soup.find_all("div", class_="grid-product__title grid-product__title--body")
a_field_3 = soup.find_all("a", class_="grid-product__link")
span_field_4 = soup.find_all("span", class_="money")

# Loop the elements "i.e. images":
for indx, item in enumerate(images): 
  dataset.append({
      'Field_01': "https:" + item["data-src"],
      'Field_02': divs_field_2[indx_it].get_text(strip=True),
      'Field_03': a_field_3[indx_it]['href'],
      'Field_04': span_field_4[indx_it].get_text(strip=True)
  })

# Create and display the dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
display(df)
```

Result:

| index | Field_01 | Field_02 | Field_03 | Field_04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Ayla_Ring_Gold_Hero_{width}x.jpg?v=1660506192 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 1 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Ayla_Ring_Silver_Hero_{width}x.jpg?v=1660506245 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 2 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Ayla_Ring_SilverY_Hero_5ee0a758-b4f7-471d-bcda-86a556cbc3d7_{width}x.jpg?v=1661231526 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 3 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Noemie_Ring_Gold_Hero_{width}x.jpg?v=1660506641 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 4 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Carolina_Ring_Gold_Hero_{width}x.jpg?v=1660506629 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 5 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Gisele_Ring_Gold_Hero_0b928b0a-542c-4ce5-bad5-dc535935a12f_{width}x.jpg?v=1670545956 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 6 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Vera_Ring_Hero_{width}x.jpg?v=1670543130 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 7 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Gisele_Ring_Silver_Hero_01fa927d-73d4-4236-87b2-28881347cd7f_{width}x.jpg?v=1670545866 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 8 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Elise_Ring_Gold_Hero_{width}x.jpg?v=1670544918 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 9 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Elise_Ring_Silver_Hero_{width}x.jpg?v=1670544859 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 10 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Jelena_Ring_Gold_Hero_{width}x.jpg?v=1660504898 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 11 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Emeri_Gold_Hero_{width}x.jpg?v=1660504754 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 12 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Adele_Ring_Gold_Hero_{width}x.jpg?v=1660504305 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 13 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Maia_Ring_Gold_Hero_{width}x.jpg?v=1660505010 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 14 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Fiona_Ring_GC_Hero_{width}x.jpg?v=1660504768 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 15 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/20210625_ALEXA.KELLEY_AKNG0003_0480copy_e2344c32-c893-4df9-9678-54a2d1e0f007_{width}x.jpg?v=1633294772 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 16 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Alaia_Bracelet_Gold_4mm_{width}x.jpg?v=1660504482 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 17 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/20210625_ALEXA.KELLEY_AKNS0004_0479copy_0bdc78af-abc4-4867-bc22-1f9c517d520e_{width}x.jpg?v=1633294849 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 18 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Alaia_Bracelet_Silver_4mm_{width}x.jpg?v=1660504542 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 19 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Isabel_Ring_Silver_Hero_{width}x.jpg?v=1660504875 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 20 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Noemie_Ring_Silver_Hero_{width}x.jpg?v=1660505177 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 21 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Juliette_Ring_Silver_Hero_{width}x.jpg?v=1660504939 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |
| 22 | https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1351/4197/products/Natalie_Ring_Silver_Hero_{width}x.jpg?v=1660505083 | Natalie Ring | Silver | /products/natalie-ring-silver | $80.00 USD |